# Swift: Could not find an overload for init that accepts the supplied arguments for my own custom object

Tags: ios, swift

I have my own custom object called Event.swift. To initialise, it takes in many string variables. Here is my class code:

```
import Foundation

class Event {
    var eventID: String
    var eventName: String
    var eventDescription: String
    var eventCategories: [String]
    var eventSecurity: String
    var authorUserID: String
    var timestampCreated: String
    var timestampUpdated: String
    var startDateTime: String
    var endDateTime: String
    var location: Location
    var reoccurDateStart: String
    var reoccurDateEnd: String
    var reoccurDaysOfWeek: String
    var eventType: String

//custom data for easy sorting
var startDate: NSDate?
var endDate: NSDate?
var startTime: Int?
var endTime: Int?
var niceStartTime: String?

init(eventID: String, eventName: String, eventDescription: String, eventCategories: [String], eventSecurity: String, authorUserID: String, timestampCreated: String, timestampUpdated: String, startDateTime: String, endDateTime: String, location: Location, reoccurDateStart: String, reoccurDateEnd: String, reoccurDaysOfWeek: String, eventType: String){
    self.eventID = eventID
    self.eventName = eventName
    self.eventDescription = eventDescription
    self.eventCategories = eventCategories
    self.eventSecurity = eventSecurity
    self.authorUserID = authorUserID
    self.timestampCreated = timestampCreated
    self.timestampUpdated = timestampUpdated
    self.startDateTime = startDateTime
    self.endDateTime = endDateTime
    self.location = location
    self.reoccurDateStart = reoccurDateStart
    self.reoccurDateEnd = reoccurDateEnd
    self.reoccurDaysOfWeek = reoccurDaysOfWeek
    self.eventType = eventType
    setUpCustomVariables()
}

func setUpCustomVariables() {
    let form = NSDateFormatter()
    form.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    form.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
    startDate = form.dateFromString(startDateTime)!
    endDate = form.dateFromString(endDateTime)!
    startTime = startDate!.hour * 100 + startDate!.minute
    endTime = endDate!.hour * 100 + endDate!.minute
    form.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    form.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    niceStartTime = form.stringFromDate(startDate!)
}

//Useful for debugging
func toString() -> String {
    return "\n\nID: \(eventID)\nName: \(eventName)\nDescription: \(eventDescription)\nCategories: \(eventCategories)\nSecurity: \(eventSecurity)\nAuthorID: \(authorUserID)\nTimestamp Created: \(timestampCreated)\nTimestamp Updated: \(timestampUpdated)\nStart Date & Time: \(startDateTime)\nEnd Date & Time: \(endDateTime)\nLocation: \n\(location.toString())\nReoccur Date Start: \(reoccurDateStart)\nReoccur Date End: \(reoccurDateEnd)\nReoccur Days Of Week: \(reoccurDaysOfWeek)\nStart Date: \(startDate?.toLongString())\nStart Time: \(startTime)\nEnd Date: \(endDate?.toLongString())\nEnd Time: \(endTime)\nNice Start Time: \(niceStartTime)\n"
}
```

However, when I try to initialize an instance of this object in my main ViewController with this code:

`let oneEvent = Event(eventID: "id1", eventName: "testName", eventDescription: "test Desc", eventCategories: ["test","categories"], eventSecurity: "test Security", authorUserID: "test author user id", timestampCreated: "test timestamp created", timestampUpdated: "test timestamp updated", startDateTime: "2015-07-04'T'08:00:00.000'Z'", endDateTime: "2015-07-04'T'08:30:00.000'Z'", location: "Your mom's place", reoccurDateStart: "2015-07-04'T'08:00:00.000'Z'", reoccurDateEnd: "2015-07-04'T'08:30:00.000'Z'", reoccurDaysOfWeek: "mon", eventType: "Phone")`

I get this error: `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Event' with an argument list of type '(eventID: String, eventName: String, eventDescription: String, eventCategories: [String], eventSecurity: String, authorUserID: String, timestampCreated: String, timestampUpdated: String, startDateTime: String, endDateTime: String, location: String, reoccurDateStart: String, reoccurDateEnd: String, reoccurDaysOfWeek: String, eventType: String)'`

```
Expected an argument list of type '(eventID: String, eventName: String, eventDescription: String, eventCategories: [String], eventSecurity: String, authorUserID: String, timestampCreated: String, timestampUpdated: String, startDateTime: String, endDateTime: String, location: Location, reoccurDateStart: String, reoccurDateEnd: String, reoccurDaysOfWeek: String, eventType: String)'
```

However, I have given it exactly what it has asked for. What is the problem?

Comment: location is NOT a string, but you're trying to give it a string... It's really not that hard to find this on your own

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what it asked for...

The parameter `location:` is expecting a `Location` and you are sending a `String`.